# Как включить подсветку синтаксиса в PyCharm?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

Как включить подсветку синтаксиса в PyCharm?
Почему-то выключилась, нашел решение на зарубежном сайте, но не понимаю что нужно делать, вот:
Checkout Settings | File Types. Probably the extension of file you need to be highlighted registered as Text file.

Подскажите где это можно найти.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно, чтобы в   *Settings -> File Types -> Python*  существовала строка `*.py` - см. красную стрелку на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда там она нет, добавите ее кликом на <kbd>+</kbd> - см. зеленую стрелку.

Затем, после ввода текста `*.py`, надо все подтвердить (дважды или трижды клавишем <kbd>Enter</kbd> - пока окошко  *«Settings»*   не исчезнет).

Не испугаетесь возможным следующим окошком после первого <kbd>Enter</kbd> и тоже его подтвердите клавишем <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе надо проверить Registered Patterns для текстовых файлов. Там не должно быть .py файлов.